# Swype keyboard in iOS8 for normal and password (secure text entry) UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, ios8

I've a login view with a normal and a secure text entry UITextFields. 
In iOS8, using Swype keyboard, hitting the "Next" key doesn't go to the next responder as with the default keyboard. 
If I open the keyboard hitting the password UITextField, it opens the default keyboard and it doesn't allow me to select Swype keyboard. 
Apple doesn't allow custom keyboards for password
**So, is there a way to know if the keyboard is missing that setting and force the next responder to open the default keyboard?**

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard change is done by default. If you just go to next responder, iOS will take care to change the keyboard to the iOS one. I'm using Swiftkey here and the change is automatic.

Are you delegating the textFields to your view controller? On mine, I use the textFieldShouldReturn method and go from one textField to the other (Swift code below):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if(textField == usernameTextField) {
    usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else {
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, my delegate looks similar, but when the keyboard should change it just send another textfieldShouldReturn.
To reproduce, you need to have a normal textfield and the second should be set as secure text entry.

Comment: Yeah, mines are this way (I'm using password as a secure entry). Maybe a bug in Swype?